# How can set up Auto-Start app without sandbox?

Tags: swift, macos

I want make my macOS app which has no sandbox be able launch itself when macOS start, I made this code below. I see that this code is putting the app in "Allow in Background" but the app does not launch. I believe it has some small issues that can be solved but I cannot find it by myself.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Button("Set Up Auto-Start") {
                setAutoStart(identifier: "bulletproofsoftwareengineer")
            }
            
            Button("Remove Auto-Start") {
                // How to disable app from Auto-Start?
            }
            
        }
        .frame(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
        
    }
    
}
```

---

```
    func setAutoStart(identifier: String) {
    let bundleURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL
    let executableName = bundleURL.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
    
    let plistContent = """
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.\(identifier).\(executableName)</string>
    
        <key>Program</key>
    
        <string>\(Bundle.main.executablePath!)</string>
    
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    
        <true/>
    </dict>
    </plist>
    """
    
    let plistPath = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
        .appendingPathComponent("Library/LaunchAgents/com.\(identifier).\(executableName).plist")
    
    do {
        try plistContent.write(to: plistPath, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
        
        let launchctl = Process()
        launchctl.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/launchctl")
        launchctl.arguments = ["load", "-w", plistPath.path] 
        
        try launchctl.run()
        
    } catch(let error) {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

And if I click on set up button more than once it shows this massage:

> Load failed: 5: Input/output error

> Try running `launchctl bootstrap` as root for richer errors.

Comment: You have to specify the path to the executable (`executablePath`), not to the bundle. And – unrelated – you can avoid the `NSString` bridge cast by exchanging the APIs `bundleURL.deletingPathExtension.lastPathComponent`

Comment: Thanks, I made that update to the codes, but still app doe not launch.

Comment: Add the `-w` flag to `launchctl.arguments` to set the `Disabled` key reliably to `false`.

Comment: @vadian: I updated the codes but still not working, the same issues of clicking more than once still exist.

Comment: Again the executable path must be `<string>\(Bundle.main.executablePath!)</string>`

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. For me and also for others could you answer this question and make needed updates that you think improve the codes? by the way I still getting those massages if I click on button.

Comment: An answer makes sense only if you roll back your question to the initial state.

Comment: @vadian: I was looking to an answer and I saw this "If you need your app to run all the time, consider adding a KeepAlive property." could you please tell me how to add "KeepAlive"? is it like that? `["load", "-w", "KeepAlive",  plistPath.path] `

Comment: No, `KeepAlive` is a key in the launchctl.plist and means that the target exeutable will be restarted when the process exits. It's not useful in your case.